# Diferenças entre as declarações de arrays

Tags: c#, array, vb.net, sintaxe, visual-basic-6

Qual a diferença entre declarar uma matriz assim:

```
 'C#
 string MinhaMatriz[] = []
 'VB
 Dim MinhaMatriz() As String = { }
```

e assim:

```
 'C#
 string[] MinhaMatriz = []
 'VB
 Dim MinhaMatriz As String() = { }
```

ou assim:

```
 'C#
 System.Array<string> MinhaMatriz
 'VB
 Dim MinhaMatriz As System.Array(Of String)
```

Comment: Utilize o método GetType (herança de object) e verifique você mesmo. Eu acredito que apesar das diversas formas de declaração, não muda em nada o que o objeto é.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essencialmente as diferenças são sintáticas. Ou seja, não faz diferença para o programa como você faz a declaração.

Note que em C# só a segunda forma é válida de fato. Na verdade nem ela, na forma descrita, afinal não existe o literal `[]` para *array*.

A terceira forma não funciona exatamente desta forma nem mesmo em VB.NET. `System.Array` não é o mesmo tipo do *array* e ele não possui uma versão genérica como proposta. Tem alguns truques para simular isto mas acho que está fora do escopo da pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Existe diferença entre uma lista e um array. As suas funções basicas são praticamente as mesmas, mas as Listas (`List<T>`) eu, particularmente, acho mais poderosas e são mais utilizadas.

```
// um array é declarado da seguinte forma:
string[] MeuArray = new string[5];



// Uma lista de objetos List<T> é declarado da seguinte forma
List<String> MinhaLista = new List<String>();
```

- Eu não conheço esse estilo de declaração "`string MinhaMatriz[] = []`"

Comment: Não foi isso que perguntei, a diferença entre declarações das arrays, exemplo: `Dim teste() = { }` e `Dim teste As Object() = { }`